# Porting delphi binary operations function to java

Tags: java, delphi, porting

Let me start to say that I have no knowledge at all of Delphi...

I'm trying to port an old app written in delphi to java, but things aren't working...

I have this function that does some binary operation to two bytes. Here's the code in Delphi:

```
function  TMainForm.mixthingsup(x, y: byte): word;
var
counter: byte;
answer1, answer2: byte;

begin
answer1             := $9D xor x;

for counter := 1 to 8 do
begin
    if (answer1 and $80) = $80 then
        answer1 := (answer1 shl 1) xor $26
    else
        answer1 := (answer1 shl 1);
end;

answer2             := answer1 xor y;

for counter := 1 to 8 do
begin
    if ((answer2 and $80) = $80) then
        answer2 := ((answer2 shl 1) xor $72)
    else
        answer2 := (answer2 shl 1);
end;

Result := (answer1 shl 8) or answer2;
end;
```

And here's my java code:

```
public static String mixthingsup(String data)
{
 byte[] conv=null;
 byte c9d;
 byte c80;
 byte c26;
 byte c72;
 byte x,y;
 byte res1, res2;
 byte res;


 conv=hexStringToByteArray(data.substring(0, 2));
 x=conv[0];
 conv=hexStringToByteArray(data.substring(2, 4));
 y=conv[0];
 conv=hexStringToByteArray("9d");
 c9d=conv[0];
 conv=hexStringToByteArray("80");
 c80=conv[0];
 conv=hexStringToByteArray("26");
 c26=conv[0];
 conv=hexStringToByteArray("72");
 c72=conv[0];


 res1=(byte) (c9d ^ x);

 for(int i=1; i<9; i++) 
 {
  if((res1 & c80) == c80)
      res1=(byte) ((res1 << 1) ^ c26);
  else
      res1=(byte) (res1 << 1);
 }

 res2=(byte) (res1 ^ y);
 for(int i=1; i<9; i++) 
 {
  if((res2 & c80) == c80)
      res2=(byte) ((res2 << 1) ^ c72);
  else
      res2=(byte) (res2 << 1);

 }

 res=(byte) ((res1 << 8) | res2);

 return Integer.toHexString(res);
}
```

When the delphi function returns CA BA for A8 77, for instance, the java function returns FF FF FF BA

Any thoughts? Any help?

Thanks, 
Pedro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
res=(byte) ((res1 << 8) | res2);
```

When you cast it to `byte` you are truncating a 16 bit value into 8 bits and so lose `res1`.

You should cast to a 2 byte value, `short`.

That said, it might be easier just to return your two bytes in an array. Like this:

```
public static byte[] MixThingsUp(byte x, byte y)
{
    byte answer1 = (byte) (0x9D ^ x);
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
        if ((answer1 & 0x80) == 0x80)
            answer1 = (byte) ((answer1 << 1) ^ 0x26);
        else
            answer1 = (byte) (answer1 << 1);

    byte answer2 = (byte) (answer1 ^ y);
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
        if ((answer2 & 0x80) == 0x80)
            answer2 = (byte) ((answer2 << 1) ^ 0x72);
        else
            answer2 = (byte) ((answer2 << 1));

    return new byte[] { answer1, answer2 };
}
```

If I were you I would separate the bitwise manipulations and the conversions to and from string. The way you have it in your question mixes the two concerns.